# Can I obtain a waiver for my J-1's 2 year residence requirement based on government financing?

Tags: usa, working-visas, j-visa

My DS-2019 form requires me to return back to my home country after the completion of my work program considering the fact that I receive government financing (i.e. salary from an institution funded by the U.S. government)

Is it possible to obtain a waiver for this kind of rule? Does this mean that I'll return to my home country and stay there for two years after the expiration of my one year J-1 visa?

Comment: Do any of the options at (https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/study-exchange/student/residency-waiver/eligibility.html#waiver) apply to you?